# Push a JSON into an existing array syntax incorrect - MongoDB

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

What's wrong with my syntax to push a JSON into an existing array?

```
> db.accounts.update({"accounts.username":"gattra"},{$push:{logbooks:[{firstLogbook:{"date":"Aug 24, 2015","location":"Brunswick,ME"}}]}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Another attempt:

```
> db.accounts.update(
 {"accountInfo.username":"gattra"},
 { $addToSet: { 'logbooks.$.firstLogbook': toInsert } }
)
WriteResult({
"nMatched" : 0,
"nUpserted" : 0,
"nModified" : 0,
"writeError" : {
    "code" : 16837,
    "errmsg" : "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: logbooks.$.firstLogbook"
}
})
```

It looks like it's saying it didn't find any matches to my criteria, but if you look at the document below you can see that there is an account with the username "gattra".

I'm new to MongoDB and I don't quite understand the websites documentation.

The document containing the array:

```
>  db.accounts.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55d6450dd745a23c6cfa2b23"),
"accountInfo" : {
    "username" : "gattra",
    "password" : "PASS",
    "userid" : 1111
},
"logbooks" : [
    {
        "firstLogbook" : [
            {
                "date" : "August 10, 2015",
                "location" : "Portland, ME",
                "routeName" : "Trendsetter",
                "grade" : "V10",
                "type" : "Bouldering",
                "time" : "4:30.05",
                "pcl" : 10,
                "notes" : "My first V10 ever!",
                "photoUrl" : ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

---

**EDIT : CORRECTED VERSION**
Thanks to @Allen Chou for the assistance.

I ended up reconstructing the accounts collection to look like this:

```
{
"accountInfo":{
"username":"broderick",
"password":"PASS",
"userid":1111
},

"logbooks": 
[{
"firstLogbook": {
    "id":1234,
    "info":[{
        "date":"August 10, 2015",
        "location":"Portland, ME",
        "routeName":"Trendsetter",
        "grade":"V10",
        "type":"Bouldering",
        "time": "4:30.05",
        "pcl":10,
        "notes":"My first V10 ever!",
        "photoUrl":""
    }]
}
}]
```

}

By adding an `"id"` field I am able to use the id as a specifying parameter. Then I put the contents in the `"info"` field.

The working query:

```
> db.accounts.update({"accountInfo.username": "broderick", "logbooks.firstLogbook.id":1234},{$push:{"logbooks.$.firstLogbook.info":{"date":"Aug 24, 2015"}}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you wanna add new document to the firstLogbook Array.

For **[$](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** in Array update, it identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array,

The basic syntax are:

```
db.collection.update(
  { <array>: value ... }, // locate array to update
  { <update operator>: { "<array>.$" : value } }
)
```

So according to the format mentioned above, this may solve your problem.

```
db.accounts.update(
    {
      "accountInfo.username": "gattra", 
      "logbooks.firstLogbook": { $exists: true }  
    }, 
    { 
       $push:
        { 
          "logbooks.$.firstLogbook" : 
             { 
               "date":"Aug 24, 2015", "location":"Brunswick,ME"
             }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: this worked, thank you! Question, though: do I need that logbook parameter in the first bracket set with `{"accountInfo.username":"gattra","logbooks.firstLogbook.pcl":10}`? I guess I'm wondering why I need to specificy a different JSON object if the only thing that matters is that I want this new JSON object inserted into the `firstLogbook` list

Comment: to expand on that, I see now that essentially, what's happening is I am specifying the array to update. But do I need to include a field and value of an object within that array? Or can I just say something like `"logbooks.firstLogbook"` with no value attached?

Comment: hmm okay, so it sounds like, on the front-end, when a user enters a new entry into the logbook, I will need to snag a field and value from another logbook entry of theirs and use that to match the array

Comment: Is it possible to deconstruct the logbooks field as
```"logbooks" : [{ "date" : "August 10, 2015", "location" : "Portland, ME", ....}, {"date" : "August 10, 2015",..}]```? I don't get it about the initial nested firstLogbook design.

Comment: so, each logbook is a set of entries containing information about a "climb" (it's an app for climbers). I want the user to have the ability to create new logbooks and switch between them, so that's why I have a list called "logbooks" and within that list I have each logbook and their respective entries.

Comment: I kind of get it. One possibly feasible advice for you is to  add new a field _id in each Entry of firstLogbook, ```"firstLogbook" : [{_id: "oid", "date" : "August 10, 2015"...}]``` then query condition would make some sense - which Logbook user want to insert entry to(every entry in firstLogbook have the same field). Besides, according to your description there will be secondLogbook, thirdLogBook..., so the front-end will have to 
"tell" the back-end which Logbook they operate on, _id act as identifier here.

Comment: I see what you mean. So something like `{"logbooks":[{"firstLogbook:{"id":1234},[{entries list here}]}]}` .. This way I can just use `"logbooks.firstLogbook.id": 1234`

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean and I made a wrong judgement. ````"logbooks.firstLogbook": { $exists: true }  ``` actually works, just edited my answer, sorry about that and you can have a try about that again. But adding _id may still be back-up choice.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for the help. I actually like having an `id` element in the logbook, so I may go with that, but it's good to know that the other way works too

Comment: Glad it helps, also enhance my understanding about the $ operator in update.